# UIButton selected content only when touched

Tags: ios

Is it possible to see the selected state content of an UIButton only when I'm touching it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're touching a button, the button is *highlighted*. Call `setTitle:forState:` to give the button the normal title (UIControlStateNormal), and call `setTitle:forState:` to give it the highlighted title (UIControlStateHighlighted). Now you'll see one title normally and the other title when you touch the button. The same thing for the other button features, like `setImage:forState:`.